# How to match this substring correctly to replace in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace, pycharm

I have a dataframe with some data and want to replace the string " | ']". The string is a space, a pipe, another space, and a bracket.

```
     ID    Stuff
0    a1     | ']
1    b2  xyz-456
```

I'm trying:

```
df1['Stuff'].replace(to_replace=' | \']',value='', inplace=True, regex=True)
```

but it only removes the space in the string

```
     ID    Stuff
0    a1      |']
1    b2  xyz-456
```

Escaping the pipe causes the regex to no longer match and nothing gets changed in the output (in PyCharm, the backslash becomes orange when escaping, but it doesn't highlight orange in front of the pipe for some reason):

```
df1['Stuff'].replace(to_replace=' \| \']',value='', inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Comment: `replace` accepts a regex. `|` has a very specific regex meaning, so you'll want to escape it, too. As an aside: if your string literal contains a single quote, you can use double quotes for the outer string which eliminates the need to escape the single quote.

Comment: How can I escape the pipe? I added '\' in front of it and now the regex isn't matching at all so nothing in the output changes

Answer (score 1):

Use a raw string when you have special characters.

```
df1['Stuff']..replace(to_replace=r" | ']", value='', inplace=True)
```

Couple things to note

1. You're not using regex to search so no need to set it true
2. Use double quotes when you have single quotes inside a string and vice versa. Use triple quotes when you have both

Comment: I think I still need to keep the regex=True since that string I'm searching is a part of a larger string, I just did not include it for simplicity. Running the code provided only removes the space in between | and ']

Answer (score 0):

df1['Stuff'].replace(to_replace=' | ']',value='', inplace=True, regex=True)